# LaTeX: cell border

Tags: formatting, latex, tabular

I would like to add horizontal border of cell in my LaTeX table (or completely redefine the table to get the same result). My current definition is:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{
    >{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l l}
    \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{1^{st}} \textbf{Category Title}}  \\ 
    \hline
        Description    & 
        \begin{tabular}{p{20cm}}
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
        \end{tabular} \\
        Effect & 
        \begin{tabular}{p{20cm}}
            Proin in tellus sit amet nibh dignissim sagittis. Integer in sapien. Class aptent 
            taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos.
        \end{tabular} \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Category table}
\label{tab:categ_list}
\end{table}
```

which looks like this:

[image]

And I would like to add horizontal line to split cells with text:

[image]

I've found a solution with `\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{CFCFCF}\hline` which looks quite good but `\hline` separates whole row, not only a single cell. I've also tried \cline but this was not working (no cell border appeared and moreover whole row disappeared).

Comment: Please have a look at the userguide of the `booktabs` package and then consider carefully if you really want such a table design.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you, I'm LaTeX beginner (have published only 2 articles until now) and just wanted to have some nice looking table in my latest "piece of art". And of course save some time. I'll look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one

```latex
\cline{2-2}
```

in the code line before before `Effect`.

I have simplified your code for two reasons:

- the header was originally missing and I didn't know what package(s) to use to run your syntax for the colors (so, sorry but colors are missing below);
- I do firmly believe that nesting more than one `tabular` environment is not necessary, you can make it with more minimal and tidy code.

My sketch:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\def\arraystretch{1.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}%[h!]
\begin{tabular}{lp{10cm}}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{$\mathbf{1^{st}}$\textbf{ Category Title}}\\ 
\hline
Description & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit\\
\cline{2-2}
Effect & Proin in tellus sit amet nibh dignissim sagittis. Integer in sapien. 
Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, 
per inceptos hymenaeos.\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Category table}
\label{tab:categ_list}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

This outputs:

[image: screenshot of output]

I hope this helps you, otherwise please comment!

Finally, as in the comment to your question by @samcarter, you may check the package [`booktabs`](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for this and future tables in this style with no vertical border lines.